# Doctrine2 oneToMany with yml file and setter/getters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have oneToMany bidirectional relationship between User and Address. In yml file, do I need to specify the user_id field for Address entity? I did that and when I generated entity getters it didn't create getUser() or setUser() instead getUserId() and setUserId()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your `Address` entity you would have a `$user` field relating to a `User` entity, not `user_id` relating to an `integer`.

Remember you are mapping in terms of entities with Doctrine, not SQL or relational database tables. Try to think in terms of your business model as much as possible, Doctrine will handle the rest and internally it will know to make a foreign key related to a user id in the `address` table.

**User mapping**:

```
oneToMany:
  addresses:
    targetEntity: Address
    mappedBy: user
```

**Address mapping**

```
manyToOne:
  user:
    targetEntity: User
    inversedBy: addresses
```

Comment: This explanation is so simple and straight forward... even 5 years on it still is a perfect explanation! Thank you